# How to combine measurements with uncertainties by least square function?

Tags: statistics

For example, I have 2 measurements:

$b_1=39\pm 3$ (with uncertainty 3)

$b_2=64\pm 6$ (with uncertainty 6)

I want to combine them with least square function ($\chi^2$), take uncertainties into account, and then generate a $b(\chi^2)$ with uncertainty. Any ideas?
Combine means I want to know how to substitute them into χ2 function when takes uncertainties into account.
$$\chi ^{2}=\sum ^{N}_{i=1}\left( \dfrac {b_{i}-\mu }{\sigma _{i}}\right)$$

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you mean by combining $b_1$ and $b_2$??

Comment: I want to use a least-square function to combine b1 and b2 and then denote the result bχ2. Combine means I want to know how to substitute them into χ2 function.

Comment: Are you asking for a value for $b_1+b_2$?  A common most probable value?  You are focused on putting the values into $\chi^2$ but have not defined what the central value is supposed to be.

Comment: I don't think its need a central value, from b1 and b2 obviously I can get $\mu$ and $\sigma_{i}$, but I just wondering how to deal with these uncertainties.